# Supercharging small engine

Tags: engine, engine-theory, small-engine, super-charger

How do I determine safe supercharged pressure and cfm for a small engine (149 cc)?
Yamaha fz 2.0 (India)
9.31 cubic inches
13.1 PS (12.9 BHp)
Fuel injected
18.4 engine cfm

Comment: At a minimum, you would need to know things like the compression ratio, the octane of the fuel that you're planning to use, whether the fuel control system can add fuel to match the increased air and whether the engine can even handle increased cylinder pressures. Without all of those, the safe over pressure is 0.0 psi.

Comment: CR 9.5:1, 89-91 octane rating, and yes I don't know if engine will be able to handle the pressure or not that is the reason I am asking the question... (Not being rude)

Comment: Also, are you wanting to supercharge or turbocharge ... just from a general usage point of view, a turbo would suit the need and be much easier to implement than a supercharger would.

Comment: Supercharge (electro boost) cause can't afford to take power from engine (already producing less power) and can't turbo charge as exhaust would not be producing sufficient enough pressure to run turbo...

Comment: You'd be surprised what a turbo can do when sized correctly.

Comment: Sounds like incredible fun.  Honestly, when my friends have done it before.  They just buy one and strap it on.  Pretty careless but only like 5 or 6 have them have blown up motors over the years.  So that's about a 1 in 10 failure rate.  I say just go for it and if you lunch that motor it's the cost of having fun.  Unless your hauling ass when the thing lets go but that's what closed course driving is all about.  You do have a closed course to test this beast out on when your all done, right?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - I'm not sure how a 150cc supercharged engine could equate to a "beast" ... but yah :o)

Comment: It would turn it into a 150cc wheelie monster!

Comment: What is your goal regarding end result BHP?  Can you afford pistons and machine work on the head to decrease the compression on the motor?  Have you looked into slotted cam shafts to change your valve timing a bit?  What year is your bike, a carburetor version might not work so good?  If you do have a carburetor can you change out your wiring harness and upgrade the bike to fuel injected?

Comment: If not any of the above, you could do it like many of friends and just strap it on and hope for the best.  AND  What's your current CR?

Comment: The engine compression is 9.5:1 and yes can afford all matching but yes don't have contacts with cam millers so slotted cam would not be easy. Engine is fuel injected and targeted increase in BHp is 12.9 BHp to 23 BHp...

Comment: And yes machining head wouldn't decrease the pressure handling capacity of engine?!